# Error en cliente http

Tags: java, arduino

Estoy intentando hacer un código que cada que se reinicie la tarjeta arduino (Arduino Ethernet conectada a Arduino UNO) se recojan valores de una solicitud http. El problema es que a veces me aparece el resultado de esa solicitud la cual es la siguiente:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 23:04:01 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.32
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 4
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DatoQueObtengo

Sin embargo a veces me marca error de conectar al cliente con el servidor, aquí está mi código:

```
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char server[] = "www.miweb.mx";
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);
#define RESTART asm("jmp 0x0000");
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
while (!Serial) {
;
}

if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}
delay(500);
Serial.println("connecting…");
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
Serial.println("connected");
client.println("GET /ServiceWeB.php?Elements=All HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: www.miweb.com");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
} else {
Serial.println("connection failed");
}
}

void loop() {
String content = "";
while(client.available()!=0)
{  
content = content + String(char (client.read()));

}

Serial.println(content);
content = "";

 if (!client.connected()) {
 Serial.println();
 Serial.println("disconnecting.");
 client.stop();

 delay(3000);
 RESTART;
  }
 }
```

Sin embargo, como dije, no siempre funciona y pues eso me indica que algo me falta en el código

Comment: tengo entendido que es C, dejáme corroborar

Comment: es java, error mío

Comment: ¿por que el tag de `java`?